# Grouping extensions in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

We have an asterisk based phone system with multiple clients connected to it.
At the moment, all the extension numbers fall in the range 100 - 9999.  But, now we have an issue where a particular customer wants to come onto our service and insists on keeping their existing extension list.

Is there a way of having extensions 700 for one customer, and also the same number range to another customer.  But yet having them belong to a different group?

I see there is a concept of groups in asterisk but none of them seem to provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at putting the different extension "groups" in different contexts in the extensions (and sip) config files?

Its been a while since I did it, but believe you would just need to give the default context to the SIP devices (in sip.conf) so that the devices for the "new" client would live in their own context and not cross contexts.

-Andy

Answer (score 2):

Andy's correct.  Extensions don't have global uniqueness, only local uniqueness within the same context, so you can create one context per customer (or "virtual dialplan" scope).  If you're using static config files (extensions.conf, sip.conf, and so on), a context is the thing enclosed in brackets in extensions.conf.

Like Andy said, their SIP accounts then reference that context.  You'll also need a shared context to answer DIDs for multiple customers and move the call to the right context-specific handler.

Hope this helps,

Troy, Cloudvox

Answer (score 0):

You could build a separate Asterisk box and put the new group in that box.  Link the two boxes via IAX.